# Game keyboard input and events

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, game-engine

I'm working on a little game engine and can't decide how to deal with keyboard input. So far, I have been handling keyboard input by catching `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages from window procedure, however this seems to me as not a great solution to handle keyboard input.

I really love the Infinity Ward 3.0 engine where you can easily change each key action using simple config file or using ingame console. I would like to do it similar.

Here is a snippet of the config file from IW 3.0 engine:

```
bind TAB "+scores"
bind ESCAPE "togglemenu"
bind SPACE "+gostand"
bind ALT "gocrouch"
bind CTRL "goprone"
bind SHIFT "+breath_sprint"
bind 1 "weapnext"
bind 2 "weapnext"
bind 4 "+smoke"
bind 5 "+actionslot 3"
bind 6 "+actionslot 4"
bind 7 "+actionslot 2"
bind ` "toggleconsole"
bind A "+moveleft"
bind B "mp_QuickMessage"
bind D "+moveright"
bind E "+leanright"
```

You can even assign other actions to keys like say something in chat:

```
bind F3 "say Hello, World!"
```

I already have config file from which I'm reading on game startup and after that  I initialize all action keys. It works, but it's really uncomfortable way to assign all keys to all actions. For keys like `A, B, C, D, E`..it's easy, because each characters ASCII code corresponds to `WM_KEYDOWN/UP` message, but for keys like `SPACE, CTRL, SHIFT` it doesn't.

So my questions are:

- What is the best way to catch keys? (Raw input/window messages/Get(assign)KeyState)
- How can I make it easy for assigning keys from config file to
  actions?
- Is it a good idea to do some event manager?

  - If so, how the event manager structure should look like?
- Should I assign numbers to all keys and corresponding actions, or strings like "PlayerJump", "PlayerForward", "FireAction"...?

Comment: Q: *"How can I [...] assign X to Y?"* A: Use an associative container for lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for late response to the thread, I haven't been at home last 2 days.
I'm done with this problem. According to my first question, I choose raw keyboard input and here is the code if anyone interested:

```
std::map<string, bool> myKey;
bool KEYBOARD_INPUT::GetRawKeyboardData(LPARAM lParam)
{
    char buffer[sizeof(RAWINPUT)];
    UINT size = sizeof(RAWINPUT);
    GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, buffer, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    RAWINPUT* raw = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(buffer);
    if(raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
    {
        const RAWKEYBOARD& rawKeyboard = raw->data.keyboard;

        unsigned int scanCode = rawKeyboard.MakeCode;
        unsigned int flags = rawKeyboard.Flags;
        const bool E0 = ((flags & RI_KEY_E0) != 0);
        const bool E1 = ((flags & RI_KEY_E1) != 0);
        const bool KeyDown = !((flags & RI_KEY_BREAK) != 0);

        UINT key = (scanCode << 16) | (E0 << 24);
        char buffer[32];
        GetKeyNameText((LONG)key, buffer, 32);
        if(KeyDown) // Press
        {
            myKey[buffer] = true;
        }
        else // Release
        {
            myKey[buffer] = false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is function for getting actual keypress states:

```
bool KEYBOARD_INPUT::KeyPressed(string key, int mode)
{
    if(mode == ONLYONCE)
    {
        if(myKey[key] && pressed_onlyonce[key] == false)
        {
            pressed_onlyonce[key] = true;
            return true;
        }
        if(!myKey[key])
        {
            pressed_onlyonce[key] = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    else if(mode == CONTINUOUS)
    {
        if(myKey[key] == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    else if(mode == TOGGLE)
    {
        if(myKey[key] && pressed_toggle[key] == false)
        {
            pressed_toggle[key] = true;
            released_toggle[key] = !released_toggle[key];
            return released_toggle[key];
        }
        else if(!myKey[key])
        {
            pressed_toggle[key] = false;
            return released_toggle[key];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code is also an answer for my other questions, I think.
If anyone was interested in full source code for this class, let me know in the comment section.

I think, I can close this thread, **my special thanks goes to @IInspectabl**, so thank you very much!

Answer (score -4):

There are lots of ways. A good way to catch keys would be by using `ReadConsoleInput()` and then
processing the key codes in a `switch` statement. As you see in the code below
you can also "bind" the keys in the `switch` statement itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




int main()
{
    DWORD        mode;          /* Preserved console mode */
    INPUT_RECORD event;         /* Input event */
    BOOL         EXITGAME = FALSE;  /* Program termination flag */
    unsigned int counter = 0;   /* The number of times 'Esc' is pressed */


    /* Get the console input handle */
    HANDLE hstdin = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );

    /* Preserve the original console mode */
    GetConsoleMode( hstdin, &mode );

    /* Set to no line-buffering, no echo, no special-key-processing */
    SetConsoleMode( hstdin, 0 );




    while (!EXITGAME)
    {           


        if (WaitForSingleObject( hstdin, 0 ) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)  /* if kbhit */
        {
            DWORD count;  /* ignored */

            /* Get the input event */
            ReadConsoleInput( hstdin, &event, 1, &count );
            cout<<"Key Code   = "<<event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";

        }

            /* Only respond to key release events */
            if ((event.EventType == KEY_EVENT)
            &&  !event.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
            {        


                    switch (event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
                    {
                        case VK_ESCAPE:
                           EXITGAME = TRUE;
                         break;

                        case VK_SPACE:

                         break;


                        case VK_RETURN:

                         break;

                        case VK_LEFT:
                            // left key   move player left
                            cout<<"VK_LEFT   = "<<event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";

                         break;

                        case VK_RIGHT:
                            // right key   move player right
                            cout<<"VK_RIGHT   = "<<event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";

                         break;    

                        case VK_UP:
                            // up key   move player up
                            cout<<"VK_UP   = "<<event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";


                         break;

                        case VK_DOWN:
                            // up key   move player down
                            cout<<"VK_DOWN   = "<<event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";


                         break;



                    }//switch

                   event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode=-1;             


        }
    }

 return 0; 
}
```

List of virtual keys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

ReadConsoleInput :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: *Game engine* and *console application* have zero overlap.